# Why am I getting "Unable to connect" when I enter http://localhost:8888/joomla/installation in url?

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp, joomla

I'm trying to install Joomla. I have installed the Joomla files, as instructed, in `C:\wamp\www\joomla\`.  In the Joomla directory there is a directory called `installation`.

`Wampserver 2.5` is online. I'm running win8.1.  Thanks in advance for any help.

---

The error message is: Unable to connect

*Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8888.
    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.*

[The error message is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUXm7.jpg)

*Is the browser unable to connect to localhost or is the Joomla install unable to connect to the database?*  I'm sorry, I can't help with that question....I don't know enough about these technologies.

I get the same error message when I try *http://localhost:8888/*

Comment: Is there more detail to the error message? "Unable to connect" could be a number of things. Is the browser unable to connect to localhost or is the Joomla install unable to connect to the database? Can you post a screenshot or cut and paste the full error? Does or did the default Apache page load on http://localhost:8888/ Also J.I.C make sure Apache is started. I've done that once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the tutorial uses port 8888 but you have not changed wampservers apache to listen on port 8888.

Dont worry its not necessary to do that, just use a standard url like this

```
http://localhost
```

and to get to the Joomla use

```
http://localhost/joomla
```

When running Joomla it is better to create a Virtual Host to run it in, to be honest its advisable for all your projects.

Here is a post that will [help you configure Virtual Hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) on any Apache server but is writtten for WAMPServer specifically.